# AWS Xray SDK : I need to extract Service Graph using boto3, observing "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-xray

I am new to AWS (coding as well) and we are using API gateways. As part of our validations, I need extract trace using AWS X-ray service. I have written below code but observing TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error.
Kindly help me on this code.

```
import boto3
import botocore
import aws_xray_sdk
import datetime
import traceback

def retrieve_xray_data():
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='accesskey',
        aws_secret_access_key='secretaccessKey',
        region_name='us-east-1'
        )
    xrayClient = session.client('xray', region_name='us-east-1')
    specificTestData = xrayClient.get_service_graph(StartTime=datetime(2019, 11, 26), EndTime=datetime(2019, 11, 27))
    return specificTestData
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is with the `datetime`. you cant call datetime like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 26)`